# Posts are not displayed in a nice grid on loop

Tags: wordpress, loops, size

I'm having a problem.

My loop of posts is displayed rather strangely. The posts are scattered. It might be due to image size or excerpt but I've made each one of them the same size.

Take a look at http://pavilionmagazine.org/

The loop works perfectly on http://www.re-forma.ro/, which uses the same theme.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the two sites, the articles on http://pavilionmagazine.org/ don't have the following in a style on each article

```
position: absolute;
top: XYZpx;
left: XYZpx;
```

(where XYZ changed with different articles). That is why it doesn't look like the other website.

Comment: Can you tell me though, why are the posts on the 1st link scattered instead of flowing nice in a grid?

Comment: Thank you for replying but you're answer doesn't resolve anything. My question is regarding the loop of posts that doesn't flow nicely like the loop in the 2nd link. I've been going through this problem for the last 2 weeks.

Comment: Solved it myself, deleted line `<div class="post" style="border:0px; padding:0;" id="baner"></div>`

Comment: So you wanted 3 articles on each line. I assumed you wanted it to look like the other site.